# How do I know if smtp server has sent my email?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Say I use smtpclient to submit my email to my local smtp server. How do I know if the email was actully sent or not?

Answer (score 6):

The bottom line is, you don't.

SMTP is a disconnected protocol, not a transacted one.  When you send an email, SMTP only knows what happens between you and your server.  It's totally possible your server might be queuing up the mail, and not sending to the end recipient because of a network problem, and you would never know.

You can request things like DSN (Delivery Status Notifications), but not all servers support them.  If your server does support them, you may want to look at requesting one.

I know this isn't the answer you want, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 4):

[SmtpClient.SendCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx) could help